# disable "stereo mix" or audio loopback in linux mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I'm new in the Linux world.

I tried my best to disable the audio loopback, but my audio-in is mixed with my audio-out, and for example in Skype, my conversation partner can hear himself from my microphone.

I tried to disable this annoying "feature" with `pavucontrol`, `alsamixer`, etc..

I'm working with Lenovo Yoga 500 on Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3

My sound card details from alsamixer:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Intel Skylake HDMI
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.